# MS Dynamics CRM 2011 output to Excel

Tags: excel, workflow, dynamics-crm-2011

I want to be able to run a workflow from right out of Dynamics that will "mail merge" into excel and attach the result into email. Something like an excel version of automerge would be amazing.

We have set templates the data would need to be pushed to, for sending onto various companies for engineer bookings.

Any ideas the easiest way of doing this?

Comment: Could you elaborate. I'm not clear on the problem.

Comment: I can mail merge into word using automerge no problems. But I want to populate an excel sheet that is then attached and emailed. Seemingly it will require some kind of fetch XML reporting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that the quick way by exporting data (there's a button on the ribbon for that). However, it's more nice if you design a function that produces a CSV-file containing what you need. The optimal design depends on the exact requirements of your task.

Comment: Thanks for your time Konrad. I want to export to a pre designed excel form. Up to 30 variations actually and email it to the supplier, ideally from one manually added ribbon button. I can manually export as you've mentioned, although the key is from a single "send to supplier" button I need to create the excel sheet that then attaches to an email and sends.

Comment: Perhaps it'd be a better solution not to do that **inside** CRM at all. You could have a desktop client (or an add-in to Outlook, for instance) that queries the database and gets you the values required for the Excel sheet. I'm assuming that you're not looking for just a report (that can be produced from CRM) but an actual spread sheet that your customer can play around with. Correct?

Comment: It wouldnt really matter if they can have a play around.  they want to receive in .xls format, and i need to populate this in the exact same way a mail merge would work into word, it just seems limited possibility into excel, unless of course i need to do a little more research into custom built reports?  Sorry if this isnt too clear.

Comment: I will look into SSRS and try to use BIDS and visual studio to create the reports I need. Konrad, again, thanks for your time.

Comment: I don't think reporting is the way to go if you want the users to do more than just watching. You'll need to query the database and it might be a good idea to do that from an external program (that you'll write). How many different entities are involved in the final report data?

Comment: has to be internal to dynamics.  Only 1 custom entity involved.  Taking activities that have been already added to a booking run and exporting to a set template .xls output.  There could be hundreds of these created per day.

Comment: I'm not seeing any straight-forward way to solve it easily in CRM internally... Why does it have to be that way, by the way?

Comment: my department head wants it that way, for ease of use for the end user and speed i presume. and so that it can be help in the dynamics database as related records to refer back to.